# How to reference text file for use with Scanner in Android

Tags: java, android, file, text

I'm trying to read from a text file using java.util.Scanner. I have tried using getAssets() and putting the file in the assets folder , but I get the error "getAssets() is undefined for the type Unscramble"

Here is the code of the method which needs to read the text file

```
public static String go(String word) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        String line;
        word = Alphabetize(toAList(word));
        String solution = "";
        Scanner in = new Scanner(getAssets().open("wordlist.txt")); //gives error
        while(in.hasNext()){
            line = in.nextLine();
            if(word.equals(Alphabetize(toAList(line))))
            {
                System.out.println(line);
                solution=solution +"\n"+line;
            }
        }
        return "solution";
    }
    public static String hello()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
```

edit: I also tried using the raw directory, but the automatically genereated R file is seeing my text file as an int. I don't know why this is.

Comment: Assets is a good way to go, can you post some more code so that I can help you debug the assets problem? Show the whole activity.

Comment: R file stores only int ids. You are responsible to query your objects based on these ids with the corresponding methods of the activity class.

Comment: Hope you would be accessing the go() from your Activity itself...?

Answer (score 0):

Put your file in the **raw** folder, and use `getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.the_file)` to get an `InputStream` to it.

It is "seeing it as an int" because everything in the **res** folder is converted into a resource that is referenced by identifier (integers).  The `R` class is auto-generated.